# Tools for knowing if a word is commonly known

Tags: vocabulary

I came across someone using the word "animadvert". I didn't think it was a real English word, but a web search indicates that it is.

I suspect that it's a word likely to be unknown to most English speakers. Are there any tools that I can use to confirm or deny this?

Comment: Try this google tool: http://books.google.com/ngrams See ya, Jeysmith.

Comment: I've not heard of that word, but I know of no way to tell for sure how unknown it would be to others. One funny thing about words is that, the longer we know a word, the more we tend to presume others probably know it as well. More than once, I've been surprised because a person I was communicating with didn't know the word _thrice_. I thought it was common; apparently not. That's the way it is with words; either we know them, or we don't. More common words may be more widely known, so Ngrams and OneLook may provide clues, but, in the end, we are left with only clues, not definitive answers.

Comment: According to the [help/on-topic], requests for resources are out of scope for this site.

Comment: You can use usage frequency in a corpus to try to prove this, but you can't really prove empirically that "most" English speakers aren't aware of that word.

Answer (score 3):

## GloWbE

It shows the statistics of how a word is used from 1.8 million web pages in 20 different English-speaking countries.

http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/ (Corpus of Global Web-Based English)

## ngrams and bigrams

Word usage across years in large number of books for analyzing the trend.

http://books.google.com/ngrams (Mentioned by @jeysmith)

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n-grams%20%22animadvert%22&lk=2 (bigrams)

http://googlebooks.byu.edu/ (American or British corpus)

## OneLook

A number of dictionaries that have word definitions, for evaluating the importance of the words.

http://www.onelook.com/?w=animadvert&ls=a (Mentioned by mod @J.R.)

## Twitter

Twitter is a good channel for knowing daily usage of certain word.
For an uncommon word like "animadvert", only a few people mention it within a day. It differs from common words that appear much more times per day. (they almost appear multiple times per second)

https://twitter.com/search-home

P.S. Remember to use "All" filter on the top to reveal better result

## Selected Dictionary (Restricted use of common word only)

Find some dictionaries that list out common words only and use only common words to explain an entry. Verify if the word "animadvert" exists in there or not.

## Examination

SAT, IELTS, GRE wordlists cover common words that people use around the world. If the word "animadvert" is not included, unsurprisingly, numbers of foreigners (non-US people) would not understand the word.

Comment: On Twitter, the people mentioning it seem to be spam accounts, just generating random gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

One good approach is to combine [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/), a [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/) and [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams).

First, search for synonyms of given word using thesaurus. If you know any common ones, good. If not - use dictionary to find ones that match your word closely.

When you have a set of reasonable words, enter them in ngram. While the graph of given word alone is mostly meaningless, having a set of graphs comparing frequency of various synonyms easily allows you to decide whether [pulchritudinous](http://thesaurus.com/browse/pulchritudinous) is more or less common than [beautiful, gorgeous, lovely, and dazzling](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pulchritudinous%2Cbeautiful%2Cgorgeous%2Clovely%2Cdazzling&year_start=1990&year_end=2013&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpulchritudinous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgorgeous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clovely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdazzling%3B%2Cc0).